# Browser crashes/hangs system on low-spec machine under Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, crash, memory-usage

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 110S I recently installed Xubuntu 17.10.1 on. It has a 1.6Ghz Celeron N3060, 2gb ram, and 32gb SSD. Most of time Xubuntu runs great on it. However, I keep running into system lockup/crash/hang issues, which seem to always occur when too many browser tabs get opened, and especially when one or more has heavier footprint content. Google Maps in particular does it pretty readily. When this happens, the system is typically too unresponsive to even switch tty sessions to kill the process. It usually won't switch, and when it does it will hang after I input my password. I don't know what else I can do, so I usually end up just restarting with the power button. The browser I've been using is Chromium, but Firefox does the same thing. Note that I'm aware adjusting my tab habits is part of the solution here, but what can be tricky is when I open up something that's heavier footprint than I thought it would be.

Is there a way I can prevent this from being able to happen? Some way of limiting the amount of resources Chromium has access to, such that there's still enough left over to kill it if needed? What's the best approach here? This is happening quite a bit; is it possible bad memory is a factor?

Comment: Two solutions here: 1. use terminal web-browser as `links2` or `elinks` (it is a joke); 2. buy more RAM, it's cheap. Your CPU [supports 8Gb](https://ark.intel.com/products/91832/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N3060-2M-Cache-up-to-2_48-GHz?q=N3060).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have swap enabled, i.e., does `free` list any swap space?

Here's a trick I learned from running Android Studio and a modern web browser on 4GB of memory:

1. Add the line `kernel.sysrq=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and run `sysctl -p`. This will enable all <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd> commands.
2. When your system freezes due to running out of memory, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to manually invoke the OOM killer. For me, this kills the program causing the memory pressure every time, but YMMV.